# convert decimal number to fraction in javascript or closest fraction

Tags: javascript

So i want to be able to convert any decimal number into fraction. In both forms such as one without remainder like this: `3/5` or with remainder: `3 1/4`.

what i was doing is this..

lets say i have number .3435.

- Calculate amount of digits after decimals.
- multiply by 10 with power of the amount before number.
- then **somehow** find greatest common factor.

Now i don't know how to find GCF. And nor i know how to implement logic to find fraction that represents a number closely or in remainder form if exact fraction doesn't exists.

code i have so far: (testing)

```
x = 34/35;
a = x - x.toFixed();
tens = (10).pow(a.toString().length - 2);

numerator = tens * x;
denominator = tens;
```

Comment: Something like http://www.mathsisfun.com/converting-decimals-fractions.html

Comment: Then take a look at something like [fraction.js](https://github.com/ekg/fraction.js)

Comment: The major problem that you *will* face is that floating point numbers *cannot* handle values exactly (unless said values happen to be powers of two or sums thereof).

Comment: https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js/ is worth a look too

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your first 2 steps are reasonable.

But what you should do is for the numerator and denominator calculate the [Greatest Common Divisor (GCD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) and then divide the numerator and denominator with that divisor to get the fraction you want.

GCD is rather easy to calculate. Here is [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm):

```
var gcd = function(a, b) {
  if (!b) return a;

  return gcd(b, a % b);
};
```

**Edit**

I've added a fully working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QrhQ/5/).

Comment: What do you get with 0.3435?

Comment: @Xotic750: Obviously there needs to be a limit check since the nature of fractions. Something like `if (b < 0.0000001) return a;` but the theory is still sound.

Comment: I updated his fiddle with some stuff that gives correct answer http://jsfiddle.net/5QrhQ/3/.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I wasn't knocking the theory or your answer, I was just pointing out the fact that there are other things to consider, and using someone else's efforts may be a more effective solution, unless you are doing this as some kind of learning. :)

Comment: what do you think of it now?

Comment: @Xotic750: Yes. You should always try not to reinvent the wheel but as you pointed out this is probably for learning.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: `parseInt` is one way to go. Another is [`Math.floor`](http://jsfiddle.net/5QrhQ/5/).

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen Answer is Simple, Aesthetic and Perfect

Comment: Doesn't work as well with negative decimals. For example fraction of -3.00001 results in -4/1 and of -3.0000 in -3/1.

Comment: 2/6 returns something weired either: 333333333333333/1000000000000000 - due to insanitized digital representation....

Answer (score 16):

Unless you are willing to work on developing something yourself then I would suggest using a library that someone has already put effort into, like [fraction.js](https://github.com/ekg/fraction.js)

Javascript

```
var frac = new Fraction(0.3435);

console.log(frac.toString());
```

Output

```
687/2000
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/hyc23/)

Comment: It seems like this one doesn't work with trailing digits decimals

Answer (score 13):

You can use brute force test on different denominators and retain the result that has least error.

The algorithm below is an example of how you might go about this, but, suffers from being inefficient and limited to searching for denominators up to 10000.

```js
function find_rational( value, maxdenom ) {
  console.clear();
  console.log( "Looking up: " + value );
  let best = { numerator: 1, denominator: 1, error: Math.abs(value - 1) }
  if ( !maxdenom ) maxdenom = 10000;
  for ( let denominator = 1; best.error > 0 && denominator <= maxdenom; denominator++ ) {
    let numerator = Math.round( value * denominator );
    let error = Math.abs( value - numerator / denominator );
    if ( error >= best.error ) continue;
    best.numerator = numerator;
    best.denominator = denominator;
    best.error = error;
    console.log( "Intermediate result: "
                   + best.numerator + "/" + best.denominator
                   + " (" + ( best.numerator/best.denominator)
                   + " error " + best.error + " )" );
  }
  console.log( "Final result: " + JSON.stringify( best ) );
  return best;
}
  
function calc() {
    const value = parseFloat( $("#myInput").val() );
    if ( isNaN(value) ) {
        $( "#myResult" ).val( "NaN" );
        return;
    }
    const rational = find_rational( value, 10000 );
    $("#myResult").val( rational.numerator
                        + " / " + rational.denominator
                        + " ( Error: " + rational.error + " )" );
}

calc();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<P>
Enter a decimal number:<BR/>
<INPUT type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput" value=".3435" onkeyup="calc()"/><BR/>
</P>

<P>
Resulting Rational:<BR/>
<INPUT name="myResult" id="myResult" value=""/><BR/>
</P>
```

The above determines the .3435 as a fraction is 687 / 2000.

Also, had you gave it PI (e.g. 3.1415926) it produces good looking fractions like 22/7 and 355/113.

Comment: don't you think this maybe a little bit inefficient way to do it.

Comment: I did say it was inefficient, nevertheless, it is a simple answer.

Comment: This is the actual best answer! It can correctly convert `0.5555555555555555` to `"5/9"`. Other answers cannot do that.

Answer (score 11):

I get very poor results using the GCD approach. I got much better results using an iterative approach.

For example, here is a very crude approach that zeros in on a fraction from a decimal:

```
function toFraction(x, tolerance) {
    if (x == 0) return [0, 1];
    if (x < 0) x = -x;
    if (!tolerance) tolerance = 0.0001;
    var num = 1, den = 1;

    function iterate() {
        var R = num/den;
        if (Math.abs((R-x)/x) < tolerance) return;

        if (R < x) num++;
        else den++;
        iterate();
    }

    iterate();
    return [num, den];
}
```

The idea is you increment the numerator if you are below the value, and increment the denominator if you are above the value.

Comment: man, you are awesome, all other failed except yours...

Comment: Should be rewritten to avoid recursion to boost performance

Comment: Iterative approach (with benchmark to compare) posted in my answer below.

Comment: Actually, why is it `Math.abs((R-x)/x) < tolerance` instead of `Math.abs(R-x) < tolerance`?

Comment: `tolerance` as I defined it would be the "relative tolerance". `tolerance` as you defined it would be the "absolute tolerance". If absolute tolerance is fine for your application, then you can use it.

Answer (score 10):

One quick and easy way of doing it is

```
getFraction = (decimal) => {
  for(var denominator = 1; (decimal * denominator) % 1 !== 0; denominator++);
  return {numerator: decimal * denominator, denominator: denominator};
}
```

Comment: `getFraction(0.003076991306616206)` takes over 10 seconds, but it works well enough

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find the greatest common divisor.

```
function reduce(numerator,denominator){
  var gcd = function gcd(a,b){
    return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a;
  };
  gcd = gcd(numerator,denominator);
  return [numerator/gcd, denominator/gcd];
}
```

This will provide you with the following results on your console

```
reduce(2,4);
// [1,2]

reduce(13427,3413358);
// [463,117702]
```

So by continuing from already what you have,

```
var x = 34/35;
var a = x - x.toFixed();
var tens = Math.pow(10,a.toString().length - 2);

var numerator = tens * x;
var denominator = tens;

reduce(numerator,denominator);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4652513/1998725

Answer (score 3):

I had researched all over the website and I did combine all code into one, Here you go!

```
function fra_to_dec(num){
    var test=(String(num).split('.')[1] || []).length;
    var num=(num*(10**Number(test)))
    var den=(10**Number(test))
    function reduce(numerator,denominator){
        var gcd = function gcd(a,b) {
            return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a;
        };
        gcd = gcd(numerator,denominator);
        return [numerator/gcd, denominator/gcd];
    }
    return (reduce(num,den)[0]+"/"+reduce(num,den)[1])
}
```

This code is very easy to use! You can even put **number** in this function!

Comment: hey there seems to be a lot going on, i'd love some comments on overall steps taking places thanks

Answer (score 2):

The tricky bit is not letting floating points get carried away.

Converting a number to a string  restrains the trailing digits,

especially when you have a decimal with an integer, like 1.0625.

You can round off clumsy fractions, by passing a **precision** parameter.

Often you want to force a rounded value **up**, so a third parameter can specify that.

(e.g.; If you are using a precision of 1/64, the smallest return for a non-zero number will be 1/64, and not 0.)

```
Math.gcd= function(a, b){
    if(b) return Math.gcd(b, a%b);
    return Math.abs(a);
}
Math.fraction= function(n, prec, up){
    var s= String(n), 
    p= s.indexOf('.');
    if(p== -1) return s;

    var i= Math.floor(n) || '', 
    dec= s.substring(p), 
    m= prec || Math.pow(10, dec.length-1), 
    num= up=== 1? Math.ceil(dec*m): Math.round(dec*m), 
    den= m, 
    g= Math.gcd(num, den);

    if(den/g==1) return String(i+(num/g));

    if(i) i= i+' and  ';
    return i+ String(num/g)+'/'+String(den/g);
}
```

**Math.roundFraction(.3435,64);   value: (String) 11/32**

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @chowey answer, which contained recursive implementation of finding close fraction for a decimal value within given tolerance, here is better (see benchmark), iterative version of it.

```js
function toFractionIterative(x, epsilon = 0.0001) {
    if (x == 0) return [0, 1];
    const a = Math.abs(x);
    let n = 0;
    let d = 1;
    let r;
    while (true) {
        r = n / d;
        if (Math.abs((r - a) / a) < epsilon) {
            break;
        }
        if (r < a) {
            n++;
        }
        else {
            d++;
        }
    }
    return [x < 0 ? -n : n, d];
}
```

[Benchmark](https://perf.link/#eyJpZCI6InhzazRxOXg2Ynp0IiwidGl0bGUiOiJGaW5kaW5nIG5pY2UgZnJhY3Rpb24gZm9yIGEgZGVjaW1hbCB3aXRoaW4gdGhlIGdpdmVuIHRvbGVyYW5jZSIsImJlZm9yZSI6ImZ1bmN0aW9uIHRvRnJhY3Rpb25SZWN1cnNpdmUoeCwgdG9sZXJhbmNlKSB7XG4gICAgaWYgKHggPT0gMCkgcmV0dXJuIFswLCAxXTtcbiAgICBpZiAoeCA8IDApIHggPSAteDtcbiAgICBpZiAoIXRvbGVyYW5jZSkgdG9sZXJhbmNlID0gMC4wMDAxO1xuICAgIHZhciBudW0gPSAxLCBkZW4gPSAxO1xuXG4gICAgZnVuY3Rpb24gaXRlcmF0ZSgpIHtcbiAgICAgICAgdmFyIFIgPSBudW0vZGVuO1xuICAgICAgICBpZiAoTWF0aC5hYnMoKFIteCkveCkgPCB0b2xlcmFuY2UpIHJldHVybjtcblxuICAgICAgICBpZiAoUiA8IHgpIG51bSsrO1xuICAgICAgICBlbHNlIGRlbisrO1xuICAgICAgICBpdGVyYXRlKCk7XG4gICAgfVxuXG4gICAgaXRlcmF0ZSgpO1xuICAgIHJldHVybiBbbnVtLCBkZW5dO1xufVxuXG5mdW5jdGlvbiB0b0ZyYWN0aW9uSXRlcmF0aXZlKHgsIGVwc2lsb24gPSAwLjAwMDEpIHtcblx0aWYgKHggPT0gMCkgcmV0dXJuIFswLCAxXTtcblx0Y29uc3QgYSA9IE1hdGguYWJzKHgpO1xuXHRsZXQgbiA9IDA7XG5cdGxldCBkID0gMTtcblx0bGV0IHI7XG5cdHdoaWxlICh0cnVlKSB7XG5cdFx0ciA9IG4gLyBkO1xuXHRcdGlmIChNYXRoLmFicygociAtIGEpIC8gYSkgPCBlcHNpbG9uKSB7XG5cdFx0XHRicmVhaztcblx0XHR9XG5cdFx0aWYgKHIgPCBhKSB7XG5cdFx0XHRuKys7XG5cdFx0fVxuXHRcdGVsc2Uge1xuXHRcdFx0ZCsrO1xuXHRcdH1cblx0fVxuXHRyZXR1cm4gW3ggPCAwID8gLW4gOiBuLCBkXTtcbn1cblxuY29uc3QgZXhhbXBsZXMgPSBbLi4uQXJyYXkoMTAwKS5rZXlzKCldLm1hcChfID0%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%3D%3D) (tl;dr: recursive 1,589 ops/s, iterative 5,955 ops/s; use iterative approach)

Answer (score 1):

```
let v = 3.141592;
document.write(d2f(v)); // 392699/125000
function d2f(v) // decimal to fraction
{
    if (Math.floor(v) == v) return v + '/' + 1;
    v = Math.abs(v);
    let ret = .01,            // rounding error tolerance
        td = v-Math.floor(v), // trailing digits
        r = 1/td,             // reciprocal
        d = r,                // start building denominator
        lim = 20;             // max loop limit
    for (let i = 0; i < lim; i++)
    {
        td = r-Math.floor(r);
        if (Math.abs(r-Math.round(r)) < ret) break;
        r = 1/td;
        d *= r;
    }
    return Math.round(d*v) + '/' + Math.round(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this for 16ths

```
function getfract(theNum){
    var input=theNum.toString();
    var whole = input.split(".")[0];
    var rem = input.split(".")[1] * .1;
    return(whole + " " + Math.round(rem * 16) + "/16");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function decimalToFraction(num) {
    let numsAfterDecPoint = num.toString().split('.')[1] ? num.toString().split('.')[1].length : 0;

    let numerator = num * Math.pow(10, numsAfterDecPoint);
    let denominator = Math.pow(10, numsAfterDecPoint);

    console.log(numerator + " / " + denominator)

    let d = GCD(numerator,denominator)

    return numerator / d + " / " + denominator / d

}

console.log(decimalToFraction(0.5)); // 5 / 10 => 1 / 2

console.log(decimalToFraction(178.45)); // 17845 / 100 => 3569 / 20

function GCD(a,b) {
    let r = 0;

    while(b != 0) {
        r = a % b 
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }

    return a;
}
```