# How can I keep fraction formatting using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

My code is focused on cooking (Banana Bread recipe). Depending on the number of people, I will sometimes make two Banana Bread's as opposed to one. Thus, I use the selection tool to account for this by changing the amount of each ingredient. Yet, my problem is JavaScript outputting decimals instead of fractions. I want to keep the numbers in fractions.

**Ideal**
If 1 was selected, it would say 2 cups flour, **½** tsp salt.
If 2 was selected, it would say 4 cups flour, 1 tsp salt.
If 3 was selected, it would say 6 cups flour, **1 ½** tsp salt.

**What actually happens:**

If 1 was selected, it would say 2 cups flour, 0.5 tsp salt.
If 2 was selected, it would say 4 cups flour, 1 tsp salt.
If 3 was selected, it would say 6 cups flour, 1.5 tsp salt.

**Code:**

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick() {
  document.getElementById("amount").innerText = 2;
  document.getElementById("amount2").innerText = 1 / 2;
  var n1 = document.getElementById("amount").innerText;
  var n2 = document.getElementById("amount2").innerText;
  var selection = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

  if (selection === 'a') {
    document.getElementById('amount').innerText = n1;
    document.getElementById('amount2').innerText = numberToFraction(n2);
  }

  if (selection === 'b') {
    document.getElementById('amount').innerText = n1 * 2;
    document.getElementById('amount2').innerText = n2 * 2;
  }

  if (selection === 'c') {
    document.getElementById('amount').innerText = n1 * 3;
    document.getElementById('amount2').innerText = numberToFraction(n2 * 3)
  }
}

var numberToFraction = function(amount) {
  // This is a whole number and doesn't need modification.
  if (parseFloat(amount) === parseInt(amount)) {
    return amount;
  }
  // Next 12 lines are cribbed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23575406.
  var gcd = function(a, b) {
    if (b < 0.0000001) {
      return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, Math.floor(a % b));
  };
  var len = amount.toString().length - 2;
  var denominator = Math.pow(10, len);
  var numerator = amount * denominator;
  var divisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
  numerator /= divisor;
  denominator /= divisor;
  var base = 0;
  // In a scenario like 3/2, convert to 1 1/2
  // by pulling out the base number and reducing the numerator.
  if (numerator > denominator) {
    base = Math.floor(numerator / denominator);
    numerator -= base * denominator;
  }
  amount = Math.floor(numerator) + '/' + Math.floor(denominator);
  if (base) {
    amount = base + ' ' + amount;
  }
  return amount;
};
```

```html
<label> How many Banana Bread's are you making? </label>
<!-- Selection -->
<select id="quantity">
  <option value="a">1</option>
  <option value="b">2</option>
  <option value="c">3</option>
</select><br><br>


<!-- Button -->
<button id="button" type="button">Let's get started!</button><br><br>


<!-- HTML Recipe -->
<p>

  Step 1: Add
  <span id="amount">2</span> cups flour and
  <span id="amount2"> &frac12;</span> tsp salt into a large, dry bowl.
</p>
```

Comment: My last edit on the other post works fine with x.5 values as indicated by your code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning values a, b, c to the options 1, 2, 3, just use the latter value: it is more intuitive. You can directly use that value for the multiplication instead of doing three different `if` blocks. You can also do away with the button, since you could just respond to the change in the select-list.

For the particular display of fractions, I would suggest putting all that logic in a class, which you could call `Rational`. It would keep numerator and denominator separate and allow to do multiplication (and other operations) on it, and to display the result with the desired output format. This way you isolate that formatting logic from the recipe logic.

Here is such a `Rational` class: it could be easily extended to do more than multiplication (e.g. addition, division, negation, inversion, ...):

```js
const gcd = (a, b) => b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;

class Rational {
    constructor(num, denom = 1) {
        if (num % 1 || denom % 1) throw "Rational constructor should get integer value(s)";
        this.num = num * Math.sign(denom);
        this.denom = Math.abs(denom);
    }
    mul(b) {
        if (typeof b === "number") b = new Rational(b);
        const denom1 = gcd(this.denom, b.num);
        const denom2 = gcd(this.num, b.denom);
        return new Rational((this.num / denom2) * (b.num / denom1), (this.denom / denom1) * (b.denom / denom2));
    }
    toString() {
        const sgn = this.num < 0 ? "-" : "";
        const n = Math.abs(this.num);
        const i = Math.trunc(n / this.denom);
        const rem = (n % this.denom);
        const frac = rem ? rem + "/" + this.denom : "";
        const remainder = {
            "1/2": "½", "1/3": "⅓", "2/3": "⅔", "1/4": "¼", "3/4": "¾",
            "1/5": "⅕", "2/5": "⅖", "3/5": "⅗", "4/5": "⅘",
            "1/6": "⅙", "5/6": "⅚", "1/7": "⅐", "1/8": "⅛",
            "3/8": "⅜", "5/8": "⅝", "7/8": "⅞", "1/9": "⅑", "1/10": "⅒"
        }[frac] || frac && ((i ? "+" : "") + frac);
        return sgn + (i || !remainder ? i : "") + remainder;
    }
}

document.getElementById("quantity").addEventListener("change", onSelectionChange);
var n1 = new Rational(2);
var n2 = new Rational(1, 2);

function onSelectionChange() {
    var selection = +document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    document.getElementById('amount').textContent = n1.mul(selection);
    document.getElementById('amount2').textContent = n2.mul(selection);
}
```

```html
<label>How many Banana Bread's are you making?</label>
<!-- Selection -->
<select id="quantity">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select><br><br>

<!-- HTML Recipe -->
<p>
    Step 1: Add 
    <span id="amount">2</span> cups flour and 
    <span id="amount2">&frac12;</span> tsp salt into a large, dry bowl.
</p>
```

Notice how the last function can concentrate on the recipe logic, delegating the use of fractions to the `Rational` class, which in turn is completely ignorant of the recipe-business.

## For older JS engines...

As you comment about an error that may be related to a JS engine that does not support ES6 syntax, I add here a version of the same using old-ES3 syntax:

```js
function gcd (a, b) {
    return b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
}

function Rational(num, denom) {
    if (!denom) denom = 1;
    if (num % 1 || denom % 1) throw "Rational constructor should get integer value(s)";
    this.num = num * Math.sign(denom);
    this.denom = Math.abs(denom);
}

Rational.prototype.mul = function (b) {
    if (typeof b === "number") b = new Rational(b);
    var denom1 = gcd(this.denom, b.num);
    var denom2 = gcd(this.num, b.denom);
    return new Rational((this.num / denom2) * (b.num / denom1), (this.denom / denom1) * (b.denom / denom2));
}
Rational.prototype.toString = function () {
    var sgn = this.num < 0 ? "-" : "";
    var n = Math.abs(this.num);
    var i = Math.floor(n / this.denom);
    var rem = (n % this.denom);
    var frac = rem ? rem + "/" + this.denom : "";
    var remainder = {
        "1/2": "½", "1/3": "⅓", "2/3": "⅔", "1/4": "¼", "3/4": "¾",
        "1/5": "⅕", "2/5": "⅖", "3/5": "⅗", "4/5": "⅘",
        "1/6": "⅙", "5/6": "⅚", "1/7": "⅐", "1/8": "⅛",
        "3/8": "⅜", "5/8": "⅝", "7/8": "⅞", "1/9": "⅑", "1/10": "⅒"
    }[frac] || frac && ((i ? "+" : "") + frac);
    return sgn + (i || !remainder ? i : "") + remainder;
}

document.getElementById("quantity").addEventListener("change", onSelectionChange);
var n1 = new Rational(2);
var n2 = new Rational(1, 2);

function onSelectionChange() {
    var selection = +document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    document.getElementById('amount').textContent = n1.mul(selection);
    document.getElementById('amount2').textContent = n2.mul(selection);
}
```

```html
<label>How many Banana Bread's are you making?</label>
<!-- Selection -->
<select id="quantity">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select><br><br>

<!-- HTML Recipe -->
<p>
    Step 1: Add 
    <span id="amount">2</span> cups flour and 
    <span id="amount2">&frac12;</span> tsp salt into a large, dry bowl.
</p>
```

Comment: `const gcd = (a, b) => b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;` Hi trincot, I received an error from this line of code: "Invalid left-hand side in assignment".

Comment: This may happen if you already had defined `gcd`. Make sure you only have one definition of this. Also, what JavaScript engine are you running on? Does it support arrow functions?

Comment: For the case where your JS engine does not support that syntax, I have added the same in traditional JS to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
...

    amount = Math.floor(numerator) + '/' + Math.floor(denominator);
    //EDIT
    switch (amount) {
        case '1/4':
            amount = '&frac14;';
        break;
        case '1/3':
            amount = '&‌#8531;';
        break;
        case '1/2':
            amount = '&frac12;';
        break;
        case '2/3':
            amount = '&‌#8532;';
        break;
        case '3/4':
            amount = '&frac34;';
        break;
        default:
            amount = amount;
        break;
    }
    //END OF EDIT
    if ( base ) {
        amount = base + ' ' + amount;
    }
    return amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

To representate 0.5 as a fraction you're using the html entity `&frac12;`. The **numberToFraction()** function is actually returning a string like "1/2" though.

So you need to include a check if **amount** is 1/2 and in case it is replace it by `&frac12;` and return this instead.

Furthermore to update the span's you need to use their **.innerHTML** property instead of **.innerText** - otherwise you won't see a fraction.

Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick() {
  document.getElementById("amount").innerText = 2;
  document.getElementById("amount2").innerText = 1 / 2;
  var n1 = document.getElementById("amount").innerText;
  var n2 = document.getElementById("amount2").innerText;
  var selection = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

  if (selection === 'a') {
    document.getElementById('amount').innerText = n1;
    document.getElementById('amount2').innerHTML = numberToFraction(n2);
  }

  if (selection === 'b') {
    document.getElementById('amount').innerText = n1 * 2;
    document.getElementById('amount2').innerHTML = n2 * 2;
  }

  if (selection === 'c') {
    document.getElementById('amount').innerText = n1 * 3;
    document.getElementById('amount2').innerHTML = numberToFraction(n2 * 3)
  }
}

var numberToFraction = function(amount) {
  // This is a whole number and doesn't need modification.
  if (parseFloat(amount) === parseInt(amount)) {
    return amount;
  }
  // Next 12 lines are cribbed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23575406.
  var gcd = function(a, b) {
    if (b < 0.0000001) {
      return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, Math.floor(a % b));
  };
  var len = amount.toString().length - 2;
  var denominator = Math.pow(10, len);
  var numerator = amount * denominator;
  var divisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
  numerator /= divisor;
  denominator /= divisor;
  var base = 0;
  // In a scenario like 3/2, convert to 1 1/2
  // by pulling out the base number and reducing the numerator.
  if (numerator > denominator) {
    base = Math.floor(numerator / denominator);
    numerator -= base * denominator;
  }
  amount = Math.floor(numerator) + '/' + Math.floor(denominator);
  if (amount == "1/2") {
    amount = "&frac12;"
  }
  if (base) {
    amount = base + ' ' + amount;
  }

  return amount;
};
```

```html
<label> How many Banana Bread's are you making? </label>


<!-- Selection -->
<select id="quantity">
  <option value="a">1</option>
  <option value="b">2</option>
  <option value="c">3</option>
</select><br><br>


<!-- Button -->
<button id="button" type="button">Let's get started!</button><br><br>


<!-- HTML Recipe -->
<p>

  Step 1: Add
  <span id="amount">2</span> cups flour and
  <span id="amount2"> &frac12;</span> tsp salt into a large, dry bowl.
</p>
```

Comment: Glad I could help! =) By the way - if you find this answer useful you can vote and/or accept it.

Comment: It says that I do not have enough "reputation" to upvote yet (I am a new member). I surely will when I can though.