# Algorithm for LCM of doubles in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, int, double

I need to turn an array of doubles to ints while keeping their ratios the same and being as simple as possible. For example [0.7, 0, -0.7] should become [1, 0, -1] and [24, 12, 0] should become [2, 1, 0]. I'm not certain if this would involve getting the least common multiple of the doubles or not, and how would this be done if so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*(The code has been updated for Swift 4 and later.)*

First of all, there is no GCD or LCM for floating point numbers. You
have to convert the input to *rational* numbers first.

This is not as easy as it sounds, because decimal fractions like `0.7` cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating point number and
would be stored as something like `0.69999999999999996` in a `Double`.
So it is not completely obvious how to get from there to `7/10`.

It is therefore necessary to specify a *precision*. Then you can
use
[Continued Fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)
to efficiently create a (finite or infinite) sequence of fractions *h<sub>n</sub>/k<sub>n</sub>* that are arbitrary good approximations to a given real number *x*.

Here is a translation of [this JavaScript implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011299/1187415)  to Swift:

```
typealias Rational = (num : Int, den : Int)

func rationalApproximationOf(_ x0 : Double, withPrecision eps : Double = 1.0E-6) -> Rational {
    var x = x0
    var a = floor(x)
    var (h1, k1, h, k) = (1, 0, Int(a), 1)

    while x - a > eps * Double(k) * Double(k) {
        x = 1.0/(x - a)
        a = floor(x)
        (h1, k1, h, k) = (h, k, h1 + Int(a) * h, k1 + Int(a) * k)
    }
    return (h, k)
}
```

Examples:

```
rationalApproximationOf(0.7)      // (7, 10) i.e. 7/10
rationalApproximationOf(0.142857) // (1, 7)  i.e. 1/7
```

I have set the default precision to 1.0E-6, but you can adjust that
to your needs.

Then you need functions for the GCD (greatest common divisor)
and LCM (lowest common multiple). Here are simple implementation:

```
// GCD of two numbers:
func gcd(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    var (a, b) = (a, b)
    while b != 0 {
        (a, b) = (b, a % b)
    }
    return abs(a)
}

// GCD of a vector of numbers:
func gcd(_ vector: [Int]) -> Int {
    return vector.reduce(0, gcd)
}

// LCM of two numbers:
func lcm(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return (a / gcd(a, b)) * b
}

// LCM of a vector of numbers:
func lcm(_ vector : [Int]) -> Int {
    return vector.reduce(1, lcm)
}
```

With all these utilities, your function can now be implemented as

```
func simplifyRatios(_ numbers : [Double]) -> [Int] {
    // Normalize the input vector to that the maximum is 1.0,
    // and compute rational approximations of all components:
    let maximum = numbers.map(abs).max()!
    let rats = numbers.map { rationalApproximationOf($0/maximum) }

    // Multiply all rational numbers by the LCM of the denominators:
    let commonDenominator = lcm(rats.map { $0.den })
    let numerators = rats.map { $0.num * commonDenominator / $0.den }

    // Divide the numerators by the GCD of all numerators:
    let commonNumerator = gcd(numerators)
    return numerators.map { $0 / commonNumerator }
}
```

Examples:

```
simplifyRatios([0.7, 0, -0.7])   // [1, 0, -1]
simplifyRatios([24, 12, 0])      // [2, 1, 0]
simplifyRatios([1.3, 0.26, 0.9]) // [65, 13, 45]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Although this does work, after performing operations using the Accelerate framework and getting an array of [0.894427190999916, -0.447213595499958, 0.0], the simplifyRatios function returns [1762288.0, -881145.0, 0.0] where the expected is [2, -1, 0].

Comment: I was able to solve this by raising the default precision to 1e-9 which seems to be the highest it can handle as 1e-10 causes an exception.

Comment: @YoussefSami: It seems that normalizing the vector (so that the maximum element is 1.0) seems to give better results. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have encountered some issues with this in certain cases involving zeroes, should I continue here or start a new question?

Comment: @YoussefSami: Can you describe the issue shortly in a comment? Then I'll see if I can help or if a new question is needed.

Comment: In this line `var (h1, k1, h, k) = (1, 0, Int(a), 1)` in the `rationalApproximation()` function, an exception is thrown: "floating point value can not be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN". This currently happens when I pass in 2 negative floats and a zero with the zero being anywhere in the vector to the `simplifyRatios()` functions. No error occurs though when I pass in 3 negative floats.

Comment: @YoussefSami: There was an error in the calculation of `let maximum = ...` which should use the *absolute* value. I have fixed that in the above code.