# Loss of precision in float substraction with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to make a function to create the fraction version of a floating point number in my app with Swift. It's working perfectly right now, except when it has to build a mixed number (whole and fraction part).

As an example below, when I call the function with 0.4 it works fine, but not with 1.4 due to it has a whole part (1). It seems when I substract the whole part (integerPart) to the original quantity it loses precision. You can check that directly in a playground.

Examples:

```
0.4 -> 2/5  
1.4 -> 1 2/5  
2.4 -> 2 2/5  
0.5 -> 1/2  
0.7 -> 7/10  
etc...  



func fractionize(quantity: Float) -> String {

let integerPart: Float = floor(quantity);
var numerator: Float = quantity - integerPart;
var firstNumerator: Float = numerator;
var denominator: Float = 1;

if (isInteger(quantity)) {

    return "\(Int(integerPart))";

} else {

    do {
        denominator++;
        numerator = firstNumerator * denominator;
        println(numerator);
    } while (!isInteger(numerator) && denominator <= 10);

    if (integerPart > 0) {

        if (isInteger(numerator)) {
            return "\(integerPart) \(Int(numerator))/\(Int(denominator))";
        } else {
            return "\(quantity) couldn't be fractionized. Result = \(integerPart) \(numerator) / \(denominator)";
        }

    } else {

        if (isInteger(numerator)) {
            return "\(Int(numerator))/\(Int(denominator))";
        } else {
            return "\(quantity) couldn't be fractionized. Result = \(numerator) / \(denominator)";
        }

    }

}

}

fractionize(1.4);
```

As an extra example, it's working perfectly with 1.5 but not with 1.4, 2.4, 3.4, etc... due to exactly the same. I don't know how to make a good substraction so that the isInteger method works fine. This is my isInteger function. I already tested it and it's working fine:

```
func isInteger(quantity: Float) -> Bool {
    return floor(quantity) == quantity;
}
```

Check in a playground and you'll see what happens when you try to fractionize 1.3 or 1.4 for example.

Comment: Most probably a duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Note that 1.5 can be represented exactly as a binary floating point number, but 1.4, 2.4, 3.4, ... can *not*.

Comment: @MartinR what do you mean with "binary floating point", and how can I solve my issue to make the function work fine? I also tried before with double with no success.

Comment: `Float` and `Double` use a *binary* representation and cannot store the value 1.4 exactly. It is all explained in much detail in the referenced thread. I don't want to sound rude, but you have to read and understood that before it makes sense to suggest a solution.

Comment: Another standard reference is ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: I'm reading right now and somehow I understand the problem. But what I don't know yet is how to make it work for my case. Is there any way to avoid that behavior?

Comment: Ah, the weekly "my floating point operation doesn't work" question… Martin is right, you really, _really_ need to read up about how floating point numbers are represented in computers and how they work. This is one of the few low-level things a developer _must_ understand, even when only working in high-level languages.

Comment: Where does the `quantity` come from? Once it is stored in a Double or Float, the precision is lost and – for example – 1.4 is *indistinguishable* from 1.39999995. One possible solution is to use a *decimal* representation as suggested below. If you have to work with Float or Double then you can do the conversion only *approximately*. A well-known algorithm is to use "continued fractions", and a Swift implementation can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28352004/1187415.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should calculate by an integer to avoid the floating point precision issue. Therefore, convert the float to an integer at first.

Is what you want the following code?

```
func gcd(var m: Int, var n: Int) -> Int {
    if m < n {
        (m, n) = (n, m)
    }
    if n == 0 {
        return m
    } else if m % n == 0 {
        return n
    } else {
        return gcd(n, m % n)
    }
}

func fractionize(var quantity: Float) -> String {
    var i = 0
    while quantity % 1 != 0 {
        quantity = quantity * 10
        i += 1
    }

    var numerator = Int(quantity)
    var denominator = Int(pow(Double(10), Double(i)))

    let divisor = gcd(numerator, denominator)

    numerator /= divisor
    denominator /= divisor

    var wholeNumber = 0
    if numerator > denominator {
        wholeNumber = numerator / denominator
        numerator -= denominator * wholeNumber
    }

    if wholeNumber > 0 {
        return "\(wholeNumber) \(numerator)/\(denominator)"
    } else {
        return "\(numerator)/\(denominator)"
    }
}

println(fractionize(0.4)) // 2/5
println(fractionize(1.4)) // 1 2/5
println(fractionize(2.4)) // 2 2/5
println(fractionize(0.5)) // 1/2
println(fractionize(0.7)) // 7/10
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot @kishikawa-katsumi

Comment: Even this suffers from precision problems, they are only more hidden. As an example `fractionize(0.123458)` gives `12345801/100000000`.

Comment: I think that there is no way because it uses the float for the input.

Comment: It's just I need it for ingredient quantities conversions, and there are never ingredient quantities with such decimal numbers amount. So, it's perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to rely on *exact* number representations, you might want to look into [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html) as "normal" floating point numbers cannot express some decimal numbers exactly. See also [this nice tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdecimalnumber).