# polynomial (in n) time algorithm that decides whether N is a power

Tags: algorithm, modulo

I am a computer science student; I am studying the Algorithms course independently.

During the course, I saw this question:

> Given an n-bit integer N, find a polynomial (in n) time algorithm that decides whether N is a power (that is, there are integers a and k > 1 so that a^k = N).

I thought of a first option that is exponential in n:
For all k , 1<k<N , try to divide N by k until I get result 1.

For example, if N = 27, I will start with k = 2 , because 2 doesn't divide 27, I will go to next k =3.
I will divide 27 / 3 to get 9, and divide it again until I will get 1. This is not a good solution because it is exponential in n.

My second option is using Modular arithmetic, using a<sup>k</sup> ≡ 1 mod (k+1) if gcd(a, k+1 ) = 1 (Euler's theorem). I don't know if a and k are relatively prime.

I am trying to write an algorithm, but I am struggling to do it:

```
function power(N)
Input: Positive integer N
Output: yes/no
Pick positive integers a_1, a_2, . . . , a_k < N at random
if (a_i)^N−1 ≡ 1 (mod N)
for all i = 1, 2, . . . , k:
    return yes
else:
    return no
```

I'm not sure if the algorithm is correct. How can I write this correctly?

Comment: Note that the text of the problem uses `k` as the name of a power, N = a^k, but your explanation that follows uses `k` as a divider of N. In general, avoid giving the same name to different things! It adds to the confusion. We have plenty of letters in the alphabet.

Comment: The version of this question from the [theoretical CS StackExchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-perfect-power-in-polynomial-time) may also be of use to you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ignoring the cases when N is 0 or 1, you want to know if N is representable as a^b for a>1, b>1.

If you knew b, you could find a in O(log(N)) arithmetic operations (using binary search). Each arithmetic operation including exponentiation runs in polynomial time in log(N), so that would be polynomial too.

It's possible to bound b: it can be at most log_2(N)+1, otherwise a will be less than 2.

So simply try each b from 2 to floor(log_2(N)+1). Each try is polynomial in n (n ~= log_2(N)), and there's O(n) trials, so the resulting time is polynomial in n.

Comment: You were faster than me! Just a detail: we only need to test the prime `b`, but difference should not be too important.

Comment: @Damien non-prime `b` is also possible. eg. if input is `6^6`

Comment: @vish4071 a^(bc) = (a^b)^c, so if you can write a number as a composite power, you can also write it as a prime power. Eg: 6^6 is also 36^3.

Comment: @Damien nice observation about prime b! Given the question is of theoretical interest only, I prefer the simpler (but still polynomial) version.

Comment: Oh, yeah...that's true. I just assumed correct answer would want smallest `a`. Bad assumption on my part.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a simple math question. Suppose that we are given `N = 96889010407` which is much less than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

The question trys to figure out if N is a power where `a**k === N` for `a > 1` and `k > 1` . So we can also write it as

`Math.log(a**k) === Math.log(N)` yielding `k*Math.log(a) === Math.log(N)` yielding `Math.log(a) === Math.log(N) / k` where `k` is an Integer `> 1`.

Now remember the inverse logarithm. `Math.log(y) = x` yields `y = Math.E**x`.

This means we are looking for an Integer like `a = Math.E**(Math.log(N) / k)` for some `k` if exists. So start from `k=2` and increment by `1`.

```
 k  a = Math.E**(Math.log(N) / k)
___ _____________________________
 2  311269.99599543784    ->   NO
 3  4592.947769836504     ->   NO
 4  557.9157606623403     ->   NO
 5  157.49069663608586    ->   NO
 6  67.77129015915592     ->   NO
 7  37.1080205641031      ->   NO
 8  23.62024048697092     ->   NO
 9  16.622531664172815    ->   NO
 10 12.54952973764698     ->   NO
 11 9.971310247420734     ->   NO
 12 8.232332000056601     ->   NO
 13 6.999999999999999     ->   YES a is 7 and 96889010407 = 7^13
```

So for how long do we have to iterate? As long as `Math.E**(Math.log(N) / k >= 2`. In this case max 36 iterations since `Math.E**(Math.log(96889010407) / 37` is `1.9811909632660634` and `a` must be an integer `> 1`.

This algorithm is probably the most efficient one for this job. It's time complexity is `O(log2(N))` as we iterate `k` (the power). Had we chosen `a` to iterate then the time complexity would be `O(sqrt(N))`.

This is OK for Natural numbers but you can extend this to the Rationals as well.

Say, is `10.999671418529301` a perfect power?

All you have to do is to convert the decimal into a fraction [the best way possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71164857/4543207) to get the rational form `4084101/371293` and apply both the numerator and the denominator to the mentioned algorithm above, to see if they both give the same power which in this case would be `5`. `10.999671418529301` is `21^5/13^5`.

Note: JS `Math` object is used in the example.

Answer (score 1):

The number N cannot exceed 2^n. Hence you can initialize i=2, j=n and compute i^j with decreasing j until you arrive at N, then increase i and so on. A power is found in polynomial time.

E.g. with 7776 < 8192 = 2^13, you try 2^12 = 4096, then 3^12, 3^11, 3^10, 3^9, 3^8, then 4^8, 4^7, 4^6, 5^6, 5^5, 6^5 and you are done.

Comment: When N is p^2 for some prime p, doesn't this take sqrt(N) time? That's not polynomial in n.