# How do you call a helper function in the category.tpl file OpenCart 2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

This is my previous question: [How to convert a decimal $attribute['text']; into a fraction in opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071114/how-to-convert-a-decimal-attributetext-into-a-fraction-in-opencart)

I have a helper function that is declared in `startup.php` and defined in `helper/dec2frac.php`

I am trying to call the helper function from a `category.tpl` file with this code:

```
  <?php if ($product['attribute_groups']) { ?>
                   <?php foreach ($product['attribute_groups'] as $attribute_group) { ?>
                       <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
                        <?php /*var_dump($attribute);*/

                       if($attribute['name'] == "Adjuster Position")
                       {
                          //echo("<h1>HELLLO</h1>");
                          dec2frac($attribute['text']);
                       }


                        ?>
```

...but I am getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function dec2frac() in startup.php
>   helper/dec2frac.php

How can I call my helper function in the `category.tpl` file? 
Do I need to reference the helper function in my `category.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve same but in a different way. This following link will help, it will work with opencart v2.3x

[Not able to find my custom object in Registry - OpenCart-v2.3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367207/not-able-to-find-my-custom-object-in-registry-opencart-v2-3-0-2)

Try the above link (it is my posted question). Create a object and save it in registry and get it from registry and call the required function.

in your category.php file, get your object from registry. For eg:

```
$kt = $registry->get('ktLibrary'); //Object
$value = $kt->getSomeValue(); //function
```

object $kt will be available throughout the category.tpl file.