# PHP Memory Exhausted Error with simple fractions

Tags: php, out-of-memory, fractions

I am using [this library](https://github.com/phospr/fraction) to work with fractions in PHP. This works fine but sometimes, I have to loop over a lot of values and this results in the following error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

I can allocate more memory using PHP ini but that is a slippery slope. At some point, I am going to run out of memory when the loops are big enough.

Here is my current code:

```
for($q = 10; $q <= 20; $q++) {
    for($r= 10; $r <= 20; $r++) {
        for($p = 10; $p <= 20; $p++) {
            for($s = 10; $s <= 20; $s++) {
                for($x = 50; $x <= 100; $x++) {
                    for($y = 50; $y <= 100; $y++) {

                        $den = ($q + $r + 1000) - ($p + $s);
                        $num = $x + $y;
                        $c_diff = new Fraction($num, $den);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used `memory_get_peak_usage(true)/(1024*1024)` to keep track of the memory the script is using. The total memory used was just 2MB until I added the line that creates a new fraction.

Could anyone please guide me on how to get rid of this error. I went through the code of the library posted on GitHub [here](https://github.com/phospr/fraction/blob/master/src/Fraction.php) but can't figure out how to get rid of the exhausted memory error. Is this because of the `static` keyword? I am beginner so I am not entirely sure what's going on.

The library code is about a 100 lines after removing the empty lines and comments. Any help would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE:

1. The script exhausts its memory even if I use just this block of code and nothing else. I definitely know that creating a new Fraction object is the cause of exhausting memory.
2. I thought that there was not need to `unset()` anything because the same one variable to store the new fractional value over and over again.
3. This leads me to think that whenever I creating a new `Fraction` object something else happens which in the library code that takes up memory which is not released on rewriting the value in the `$c_diff` variable.
4. I am not very good at this so I thought it has something to do with the `static` keyword used at a couple of places. Could anyone confirm it for me?

If this issue can indeed be resolved by using `unset()`, should I place it at the end of the loop?

Comment: how about `ini_set('memory_limit', '140M')` ?

Comment: As I said, I will run out of memory if the loop gets bigger. In one case, I allocated up to 1GB of memory and still ran out. :)

Comment: I first place, why do you need that **nasty loop**?

Comment: I have to check which values produce a particular fraction.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @Martin PHP 7.1.2 :)

Comment: Can you show us your Fraction class?

Comment: This is from a library on GitHub https://github.com/phospr/fraction/blob/master/src/Fraction.php.  :)

Comment: Please copy/paste it into your question

Comment: It is about 200 to 300 lines. Won't Stack Overflow complain that there is a lot of code?

Comment: Also: 3 of your `for` loops are worthless : because your values are summed; you need to only test  values `$p + $s`, `$q + $r`, and `$x + $y` . You are running a huge amount of repetitions on your processing.

Comment: Cut down the code, remove the stuff that's not relevant to your question.

Comment: You should not need to instantiate a `new` class every iteration; simply add new values to the existing class..... this is a big server overhead making hundreds of classes rather than simply reusing the same class hundreds of times.

Comment: I need the value of all these six variables. :) That's why I loop over them all instead of directly looping over their sum.

Comment: but if you get a result with `$p = 13` and `$s = 11` this result is exactly the same as if `$p = 10` and `$s = 14` -- so you have what looks like 50% calculation repetition.

Comment: I would **highly** recommend you stop using PHP and instead explore [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) or [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/).

Comment: @Martin but I need both these sets of values. :) I need to know that the condition I am looking for is true for both `(p, s)` at `(13, 11)` and `(10, 14)`. Is there any other way to arrive at these values instead of looping?

Comment: All you need is the sum; so once you've found that the value `24` works; you can find all the parts (over 10) that fit that value: ie `(24 (max) - 10 (min) = 14)`, so there are `10,14`, `11,13` , `12,12`, `13,11`, `14,10` valid values. savng yourself 80+ processing work. for that for loop already. You maybe only need to do 10% of the work your `for` loops are currently doing.

Comment: Thanks @Martin I will look into that. Also, thanks for your advice about not creating a new class after every iteration. The library did not have any way to set the value of numerator and denominator once the `Fraction` had been created. I have added my own method to it and it seems to be working fine now. :)

Comment: The library looks very inefficient. For what you need I suggest you simply dig out a simpler process as outlined in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about Matlab @Martin. Matlab and Mathematica can do a lot of stuff that I wanted to do without any problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Various Possible fixes and efficiencies:

You have **6** `for` loops, each loop cycles a single integer value within various ranges.

But your calculation only uses **3** values and so it doesn't matter if `$p = 10; $s = 14;` or `$p = 13; $s = 11;` These are entirely equivilant in the calculation.

All you need is the sum; so once you've found that the value `24` works; you can find all the parts (over the minimum value of 10) that fit that value: ie `(24 (sum) - 10 (min) = 14)`, then collect the values within the range; so there are `10,14`, `11,13` , `12,12`, `13,11`, `14,10` valid values. savng yourself 80%+ processing work on the inner `for` loops.

```
 $pairs = "p,s<BR>"; //the set of paired values found
 $other = $sum - $min;
     if($other > $max){
        $other = $sum - $max;
     }
     $hardMin = $min;
     while ($other >= $hardMin && $min >= $hardMin && $min <= $max){
         $pairs .= $min.", ".$other."<BR>";
         $other--; // -1
         $min++;  // +1
     }
   
  print $pairs;
```

Giving:

> p,s
> 10,14
> 11,13
> 12,12
> 13,11
> 14,10

So for this `for` loop already, you may only need to do ~10% of the total work cycling the inner loops.

---

Stop instantiating new classes. Creating a class is expensive. Instad you create one class and simply plug the values in:

**Example:**

```
$c_diff = new Fraction();

for(...){
    for(...){
        $c_diff->checkValuesOrWhateverMethod($num, $den)
    }
}
```

This will save you significant overhead (depending on the structure of the class)

---

The code you linked on GitHub is simply to turn the value into a fraction and seems to be highly inefficient.

All you need is this:

```
function float2frac($n, $tolerance = 1.e-6) {
    $h1=1; $h2=0;
    $k1=0; $k2=1;
    $b = 1/$n;
    do {
        $b = 1/$b;
        $a = floor($b);
        $aux = $h1; $h1 = $a*$h1+$h2; $h2 = $aux;
        $aux = $k1; $k1 = $a*$k1+$k2; $k2 = $aux;
        $b = $b-$a;
    } while (abs($n-$h1/$k1) > $n*$tolerance);

    return $h1."/".$k1;
}
```

Taken from [**this excellent answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357170/3536236).

Example:

```
for(...){
    for(...){
        $den = ($q + $r + 1000) - ($p + $s);
        $num = $x + $y;
        $value = $num/den;

        $c_diff = float2frac($value);
        unset($value,den,$num);
    }
}
```

---

If you need more precision you can [**read this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587290/can-i-rely-on-php-php-ini-precision-workaround-for-floating-point-issue) and update PHP.ini as appropriate, but personally I would recommend you use more specialist maths languages such as [**Matlab**](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) or [**Haskell**](https://www.haskell.org/).

---

## Putting it all together:

- You want to check three values, and then find the equivilant part of each one.
- You want to simply find the lowest common denominator fraction (*I think*).

So:

```
/***   
 * to generate a fraction with Lowest Common Denominator
 ***/
function float2frac($n, $tolerance = 1.e-6) {
    $h1=1; $h2=0;
    $k1=0; $k2=1;
    $b = 1/$n;
    do {
        $b = 1/$b;
        $a = floor($b);
        $aux = $h1; $h1 = $a*$h1+$h2; $h2 = $aux;
        $aux = $k1; $k1 = $a*$k1+$k2; $k2 = $aux;
        $b = $b-$a;
    } while (abs($n-$h1/$k1) > $n*$tolerance);

    return $h1."/".$k1;
}

 /***
  * To find equivilants
  ***/
 function find_equivs($sum = 1, $min = 1, $max = 2){
    $value_A = $sum - $min;
    $value_B = $min;
    if($value_A > $max){
        $value_B = $sum - $max;
        $value_A = $max;
    }
    $output = "";
    while ($value_A >= $min && $value_B <= $max){
        if($value_A + $value_B == $sum){
            $output .= $value_A . ", " . $value_B . "<BR>";
        }
        $value_A--; // -1
        $value_B++;  // +1
    }
    return $output;
}

 /***
  * Script...
  ***/     
 $c_diff = []; // an array of results. 
 for($qr = 20; $qr <= 40; $qr++) {
     for($ps = 20; $ps <= 40; $ps++) {
         for($xy = 100; $x <= 200; $xy++) {
              $den = ($qr + 1000) - $ps;
              $num = $xy;
              $value = $num/$den; // decimalised  
              $c_diff[] = float2frac($num, $den);
              /*** 
               What is your criteria for success?
               ***/ 
              if(success){
                 $qr_text = "Q,R<BR>";
                 $qr_text .= find_equivs($qr,10,20);
                 $sp_text = "S,P<BR>";
                 $sp_text .= find_equivs($sp,10,20);
                 $xy_text = "X,Y<BR>"; 
                 $xy_text .= find_equivs($sp,50,100);
               }
             }
         }
      }
```

- This should do only a small percentage of the original looping.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about inefficiency of the original code. I am not familiar with the original library being used but a default time complexity for a simple use case being O(6) is quite massive. I am not surprised memory issues are becoming an issue.

Comment: Thank you for the insights Martin. :)

Comment: @iKnowNothing I have updated my answer code, please take a look

Comment: @Martin could you please clarify one more thing for me? Even though I was creating a new Fraction with each loop, I was storing it in the same old variable. So, why did I exhaust all my memory?

Comment: The memory was being exhausted by the *class* not by your variables.

Comment: I thought the old class instance was being destroyed after each reassignment. :) Thanks for the clarification Martin. I learned a lot of new things today.

Comment: @iKnowNothing I made final fixes to the equivilant function in the bottom code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this isn't the entire block of code you are using.

This loop creates 50*50*10*10*10*10 = 25.000.000 Fraction objects. Consider using PHP's `unset()` to clean up memory, since you are allocating memory to create objects, but you never free it up.

*editing for clarification*

When you create anything in PHP, be it variable, array, object, etc. PHP allocates memory to store it and usually, the allocated memory is freed when script execution ends.

`unset()` is the way to tell PHP, "hey, I don't need this anymore. Can you, pretty please, free up the memory it takes?". PHP takes this into consideration and frees up the memory, when its garbage collector runs.

It is better to prevent memory exhaustion rather than feeding your script with more memory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer icydemon. I really appreciate it. :)

I am adding more details in the question because adding it in comments would make it unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

134217728 bytes = 134.218 megabytes

Can you try this?

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '140M')
/* loop code below */
```

Comment: *"I can allocate more memory using PHP ini but that is a slippery slope. At some point, I am going to run out of memory when the loops are big enough."*